# ¿Cómo crear nuevos registros a partir de unos ya existentes y que los nuevos registros mantenga la misma relación?

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla que tiene una relación reflexiva de uno a muchos en una misma tabla. A partir de estos registros de deben crear nuevos IDs a partir de los que existen y mantener la misma relación entre los registros.

```
IdTareaInv  IdTareaInvOrigen
----------- ----------------
8421        NULL
8499        8421
8422        NULL
8501        8422
8423        NULL
8551        8423
8432        NULL
8500        8432
8548        8432
8549        8432
```

Los nuevos iD creados para esta misma tabla deberían mantener la misma relación que los de origen, por Ejemplo para:

```
IdTareaInv  IdTareaInvOrigen  IdTareaInv  IdTareaInvOrigen  
----------- ----------------  ----------- ---------------- 
8423        NULL---------->   10000       NULL
8551        8423---------->   10001       10000
8432        NULL---------->   10002       NULL
8500        8432 --------->   10003       10002
```

y así sucesivamente manteniendo la misma relación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin duda lo más sencillo en insertar e incrementar todos los `id` un número fijo que bien podría ser el `max(IdTareaInv) + 1`:

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT Ejemplo on

insert into Ejemplo (IdTareaInv, IdTareaInvOrigen)
select IdTareaInv + 10000,
       IdTareaInvOrigen + 10000
       from Ejemplo
       
set IDENTITY_INSERT Ejemplo off
```

Otra forma, algo más compleja, es:

- insertar las filas, y dejar que la base genere los nuevos `identity`
- durante la inserción generar una tabla de relaciones entre `IdTareaInvOriginal` y `IdTareaInvNuevo`, es decir el `IDENTITY` de origen y el nuevo.
- Con esta tabla, actualizar los `IdTareaInvOrigen` con el nuevo `Id`

Algo así:

```
create table relacion (
         IdTareaInvOriginal   int,
         IdTareaInvNuevo      int
)

-- insertamos las filas en la misma tabla, IdTareaInvOrigen  es la actual
-- generamos una tabla de relaciones del id original al nuevo identity
MERGE INTO Ejemplo USING Ejemplo AS src ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (IdTareaInvOrigen)
    VALUES (src.IdTareaInvOrigen)
    OUTPUT src.IdTareaInv, inserted.IdTareaInv
    INTO relacion (IdTareaInvOriginal, IdTareaInvNuevo);

-- Ahora sí, actualizamos la relaciones a los nuevos id
update Ejemplo
       set IdTareaInvOrigen = r.IdTareaInvNuevo
       from Ejemplo E
       inner join relacion r
          on E.IdTareaInvOrigen = r.IdTareaInvOriginal
       where IdTareaInv in (SELECT IdTareaInvNuevo from relacion)
```

Cualquier cosa, puedes verificar la idea en este [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57fda400bdddf3a9c98aba102ba71302)